# Reading Child node data in XML files C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have been trying to read XML file and writing it to another XML. I have successfully read and write data but some contents are missing as nested child node are creating issues. However i have done reading and writing with scenario if a node has one child. But to make a generic with "any num of childs" is creating issues.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"\\File Server\source_FILE.xml");
        string dest_path = @"\\File Server\dest_FILE" + rnd.Next() + ".xml";
        XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
        XmlTextWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(dest_path, null);
        try
        {
            XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName(@"Article");
            xw.WriteStartElement("Article", null);
            for (int i = 0; i < elemList[0].ChildNodes.Count; i++)
            {
                var test = elemList[0].ChildNodes.Item(i).ChildNodes.Item(0).GetType();//.NextSibling;
                if (test.Name == "XmlElement")
                {
                    int t = 0;
                    xw.WriteStartElement(elemList[0].ChildNodes.Item(i).Name);
                    while (t < elemList[0].ChildNodes.Item(i).ChildNodes.Count)
                    {
                        xw.WriteElementString(elemList[0].ChildNodes.Item(i).ChildNodes.Item(t).Name, elemList[0].ChildNodes.Item(i).ChildNodes.Item(t).InnerText);
                        t++;
                    }
                    xw.WriteEndElement();
                }
                else
                {
                    xw.WriteElementString(elemList[0].ChildNodes.Item(i).Name, elemList[0].ChildNodes.Item(i).InnerText);
                }
            }
            xw.WriteEndElement();
            xw.Close();
            doc2.Save(xw);
```

My XML files is like

```
<Article>
   <Headline>Text is here all</Headline>
      <City>
        <A>
          <B></B>
        </A>
      </City>
      <Date>15 November 2010</Date>
      <Source>
         <P>ABC</P>   
      </Source>
      <Text>
         <P> 
         </P>
      </Text>         
      <Category>abc</Category>
      <Subject>_</Subject>
      <Keyword>_</Keyword>
      <Country>_</Country>
</Article>
```

May be I have to create recursive function but I need help on this

Comment: I have done this lots of times using xml linq.  Which node are recursive?  It is better to use xml linq where you can use Descendants() property.

Comment: but can't i do without linq? because im familiar with things im working with

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq:

```
var mainDoc = XDocument.Load("File1.xml");
mainDoc.Root.Add(XDocument.Load("File2.xml").Root.Elements());
```

Now mainDoc will contain all the elements of the second file.